# How to get list of mysql servers in c# .net

Tags: c#, mysql

I need mysql servers list. I have get list of mssql server using following command.

```
DataTable dtServers = Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers();
  int AllServerCount = dtServers.Rows.Count;

   // If there are any servers at all
  if (dtServers.Rows.Count > 0){

   // Loop through each server in the DataTable
    foreach (DataRow drServer in dtServers.Rows){

      cmbServer.Items.Add(drServer["Name"]); 
    }
     // Add the name to the combobox
  }
```

Is any equivalent mysql code in c# which will populate all mysql servers?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have any discovery mechanism like MS SQL. You'd have to scan all possible network addresses for open ports.